# What options are available for gap between interior door frame and wall?

Tags: walls, door-frame, gap

There are is gap (approx 0.1cm to 0.4cm) between the interior door frame and wall as shown below. (on the left side is the wall, middle is the gap, right side if the interior wooden door frame)

[image]

What are the options available to resolve it and kindly give the pros and cons for each options. Thank you.

Comment: We need more information and a picture would be necessary. There is supposed to be a gap between the door jamb and the rough opening. Shims are used to fix the jamb in the rough opening. This leaves gaps all around between the door jamb the rough opening which are then covered by finish trim called casing.

Comment: What is the material of the adjacent wall?

Comment: @MichaelKaras, should be cement, and oil-based paint painted on it.

Comment: use a cement filler product. The problem you might have is with expansion of the frame, but maybe not.

Comment: @Ken, can I also use normal putty to fill the gap?

Comment: Putty like joint compound may not adhere like you want, may not have the same textures. Here is a product Dap 37584 Liquid Cement Crack Filler-Quart Bottle it is simple to use and dries in less than an hour, and it can be had for your lunch money $12.

Answer (score 1):

For small gaps between wooden trim such as doorframes and plastered walls I use a "Flexible gap filler" - available at any DIY store. Spending a few minutes reading the containers carefully and asking store assistants will get you a product you can try.

Description from a randomly selected product

> This flexible filler achieves a white crack-free fill between two surfaces where movement can occur. Controlled application is ideal for long linear gaps.
>
> - For flexible, crack-free filling between two surfaces where movement can occur.
> - Easily controlled application for long linear gaps.
> - For indoor and outdoor use.

Another one

> An acrylic filler for draught proofing and filling fine cracks. Can be sanded, overpainted or papered over. Solvent free formulation.
>
> - Interior or Exterior Use: Interior
> - Application Method: Knife
> - Colour: White
> - Size: 310 ml
> - Type: Ready Mixed Filler

It is often a good idea to rake out the corner first, to remove loose or weak paint. Then sand as necessary before cleaning and filling.